# How to customize the appearance of the Django change password form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to customize the appearance of the Django change password form , i tried this but nothing happened i don't know why , any ideas ?

forms.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm

class MyPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["old_password"].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
        self.fields["new_password1"].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
        self.fields["new_password2"].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
```

urls.py :

```
# Change Password
path(
    'change-password/',
    auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='user/commons/change-password.html',
        success_url = '/'
    ),
    name='change_password'
),
```

views.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
from blog_app.forms import MyPasswordChangeForm

class PasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = MyPasswordChangeForm
    template_name = "user/commons/change-password.html"
```

change_password.html :

```
<div class="form-group">
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Back</a>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

oops , my mistake the problem was in urls.py , it must be like this `views.PasswordChangeView.as_view` not `auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view`

it must be like this

```
    # Change Password
path(
    'change-password/',
    views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='user/commons/change-password.html',
        success_url = '/'
    ),
    name='change_password'
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.container{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-group label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-group input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```
<div class="container mt-5">
<h2>Change Password</h2>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_old_password">Old Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="id_old_password" name="old_password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_new_password1">New Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="id_new_password1" name="new_password1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_new_password2">Confirm New Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="id_new_password2" name="new_password2">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).